# Flash AS3 - how to randomize each frame while play

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have some quiz level 1 in frame 2-11 and frame 12 is the result of quiz, and quiz level 2 in frame 13-22 with result in frame 23..

i want to randomize a quiz between 2-11 and randomize a quiz in frame 13-22,

**Example :**

1. 1st quiz is frame 3
2. 2nd quiz is frame 6
3. 3rd quiz is frame 2
4. (... ...)
5. (n)th ... ... ...(last frame that not yet showing)

I'm using this code in frame 1 :

```
stop();
autom.play();
soal = 1;
var pic:Number=11;
var randomFrame:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*pic);
trace(randomFrame);
gotoAndStop(randomFrame);
nextFrame();
```

but the flash randomize just first time

i want to know if there is a way to make it possible to make the flash running well like what i want in **Example**???

**EDIT :**

`full code of frame 1`

```
var kunci:String,
jawaban:String,
dikunci:String,
soal:int,
betul:int,
salah:int,
hati:int=0,
nilai:int,
mcres:mcrespon = new mcrespon();
mcres.x = 20;
mcres.y = 40;
mcres.scaleX = 3;
mcres.scaleY = 3;

tbhome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,clikmenu);
tbmulai.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,cliklanjut);
function cliklanjut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stop();
    autom.play();
    soal = 1;
    betul = 0;
    salah = 0;
    nilai = 0;6;
    var pic:Number=22;
    var randomFrame:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*pic);
    trace(randomFrame);
    gotoAndStop(randomFrame);
    nextFrame();
    /*stop();
    autom.play();
    soal = 1;
    var pic:Number=11;
    var randomFrame:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*pic);
    trace(randomFrame);
    gotoAndStop(randomFrame);
    nextFrame();*/
}
function clika(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    autom.play();
    jawaban = "a";
    cocokan();
}
function clikb(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    autom.play();
    jawaban = "b";
    cocokan();
}
function clikc(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    autom.play();
    jawaban = "c";
    cocokan();
}
function clikd(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    autom.play();
    jawaban = "d";
    cocokan();
}
function cocokan()
{
    addChild(mcres);
    if (jawaban == kunci)
    {
        mcres.gotoAndPlay(2);
        setTimeout(lanjutbenar,0);
    }
    else
    {
        mcres.gotoAndPlay(16);
        setTimeout(lanjutsalah,0);
    }
}
function copot()
{
    removeChild(mcres);
}
function lanjutbenar()
{
    betul +=  1;
    soal +=  1;
    copot();
    nextFrame();
}
function lanjutsalah()
{
    salah +=  1;
    hati +=  1;
    mchati.nextFrame();
    copot();
    if (hati>=3)
    {
        gotoAndStop("gameover");
    }
    else
    {
        soal +=  1;
        nextFrame();
    }
}
function clikulang(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    autom.play();
    soal = 1;
    betul = 0;
    salah = 0;
    nilai = 0;
    hati = 0;
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
function kuncinya(sikunci:String)
{
    soalnya.text = "Soal no " + soal.toString() + "/20";
    pila.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clika);
    pilb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clikb);
    pilc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clikc);
    pild.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clikd);
    kunci = sikunci;
}

function diresumequis(batasbagus:int,komen1:String,komen2:String,komen3:String)
{
    stop();
    tbulang.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clikulang);
    tbnextlevel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,cliklanjut);
    betulnya.text = "Benar = " + betul.toString();
    salahnya.text = "Salah = " + salah.toString();
    nilai = betul / 10 * 100;
    nilainya.text = "Nilai = " + nilai.toString();

    if (nilai == 100)
    {
        komentar.text = komen1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (nilai>=batasbagus)
        {
            komentar.text = komen2;
        }
        else
        {
            komentar.text = komen3;
        }
    }
}
```

`in frame 2 till 11 are a same code like this :`

```
kuncinya("a") // the correct answer of a question;
```

Comment: any ideas please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to keep track of which frames you've been to so you don't get repeats and so you know when the quiz is done.

The easiest way to do this is probably to have an array of your question frames, and then remove the question frame from that array whenever you complete a question.

Something along these lines:

*Frame 1 code:*

```
//a var to hold the current quiz (an array/collection of frames)
var curQuiz:Array;

//a var to hold the ending frame of the current quiz
var curQuizEndFrame:int;

 //the frame number or labels that are questions for this quiz
var quiz1:Array = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
var quiz2:Array = [13,14,15,16]; //etc

//create a function to start a quiz with two parameters - the quiz array to start, and the frame to goto once all the questions have been asked.
function startQuiz(quiz:Array, endFrame:int):void {
    curQuizEndFrame = endFrame;
    curQuiz = quiz.concat(); //this copies the passed in quiz array (so you don't modify the original)

    //randomize the question order
    curQuiz.sort(randomizeArray);

    //now call nextQuestion (created below) to go to the first question
    nextQuestion(); 
}

//create a function to show the next question. Call this whenever the user answers a question - the e parameter is just there in case you want to call this function from an event handler
function nextQuestion(e:Event = null):void {
    //check if there is a current quiz, and if there are still questions left in it
    if(curQuiz && curQuiz.length > 0){
        //goto the next question in the quiz
        gotoAndStop(curQuiz.pop()); //pop removes the last element from the array and returns its value
    }else{
        if(curQuiz){
            //if we get here, it means the quiz exists but doesn't have any questions left, so go to the end frame
            gotoAndStop(curQuizEndFrame); //quiz is finished
        }else{
            //quiz hasn't started yet, do something like tell the user to start the quiz
        }
    }
}

//a randomize sort function for arrays
function randomizeArray(a:*,b:*):int {
    return(Math.random() > .5) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Then, whenever you finish a question, call `nextQuestion();` This should likely be on a next button click handler on each of your question frames.

```
nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextQuestion, false, 0, true);
```

Whenever you want to start a new quiz, call `startQuiz` and pass in the quiz array and ending frame.

For example:

```
startQuiz(quiz1, 12);
```

Comment: can u give another simple code for do this, i cant read the code well, i'm apologize for that.. | do you have an idea of my full code in frame1?

Comment: and sir, it is possible to re-create ur code above in 1 function??

Comment: I don't understand what most of your code is doing,  can you put comments beside your vars to explain what they are for? (since I don't know the language you are using)

Comment: now we can forgot of my code, but about your code above, i've tried it, but when i play the flash, `compiler error` tell me `Access of undefined property nextBtn`, should i need to declare the `nextBtn` first?

Comment: Yes, that was just an example,  replace `nextBtn` with whatever instance name you've given your button.  I don't know what each of your question frames look like, but I'm assuming there's some kind of next or continue button